# How to scroll horizontally and vertically this layout

Tags: android, android-layout

i am trying to scroll down this main layout horizontally and vertically , if this main layout does not fit into the user phone while the user holding the phone vertically or horizontally, he has the option scroll it. thanks

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/description"
        android:lines="4"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:background="@drawable/text_background"
        />



    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lgn"
        android:lines="2"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:gravity="center" />

     <Button 
         android:id="@+id/click_login"  
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textColor="@color/white"
         android:textStyle="bold"

         />


     <TextView 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="@string/rgs"
         android:textColor="@color/text"
         android:lines="2"
         android:gravity="center"

         />


       <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="6"
        />
       <TextView 

           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="1dip"
           android:lines="10"
           android:background="#8B8989"

           />

       <TextView 
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/foter"
           android:lines="2"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:textColor="@color/Blue"

           />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use scrollview above to linearlayout......

Answer (score 0):

I edited your xml code as below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >


 <ScrollView
   android:id="@+id/scro1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_x="***dp"
   android:layout_y="***dp">
   <LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_x="***dp"
android:layout_y="***dp">
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/description"
    android:lines="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:background="@drawable/text_background"
    />



<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/lgn"
    android:lines="2"
    android:textColor="@color/text"
    android:gravity="center" />

 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/click_login"  
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="@color/white"
     android:textStyle="bold"

     />


 <TextView 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="@string/rgs"
     android:textColor="@color/text"
     android:lines="2"
     android:gravity="center"

     />


   <TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:lines="6"
    />
   <TextView 

       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="1dip"
       android:lines="10"
       android:background="#8B8989"

       />

   <TextView 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/foter"
       android:lines="2"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:textColor="@color/Blue"

       />
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

***dp represents from where you want to scroll the `LinearLayout`.

Comment: i shall be very thankful to you for a quick reply ,i tried your code it is still giving error which is "This ScrollView layout or its LinearLayout parent is possibly useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view" , and there is no attribute for layout like android:layout_x .

Answer (score 0):

did you try putting everything inside a "ScrollView"? :-)

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout>
        <!-- Your linear layout here -->
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for quick reply , will you please wrap my code in your solution because i tried your way and it is not working .thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use below coding.

Vertical scrolling:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical">
          // all views to scroll
</LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

horizontal scrolling:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
          // all views to scroll
    </LinearLayout>
 </HorizontalScrollView>
```